# Ruby Check date to know if it falls within a date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Background on Application.**
Users write test's and their results expire after 5 years.
I need to give them the option to rewrite after 3 years up to 5 years.
I have the `expiry_date` which is set to 5 years from the date it got created.

**My Question**
How would I write my statement
I have the ActiveSupport gem
`expiry_date` is in Date format

```
if expiry_date < 3.years.ago && expiry_date > 5.years.ago
#Above is checking the date itself which is not right
```

**What I'm trying to achieve.**

```
expiry_date = Mon, 25 Mar 2024  #Was created on 25 Mar 2019 (Created_date not a field in db)

# Statement check's if it is past 3 years (from created) but less than 5 years(from created)

returns True

#Any where outside the range returns False
```

**My thoughts**

Would need to get today's date. Then see where it is in the 5 year time frame and whether it has been between 3 and 5 years.
It would need to be accurate to the day

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `expiry_date` marks the upper bound, i.e. 5 years after the initial test. The lower bound is 2 years earlier, i.e. `expiry_date - 2.years`. For your check you have to determine whether today is between these two dates, i.e. `Date.today.between?(expiry_date - 2.years, expiry_date)`

Comment: @Stefan I wanted to over complicate it to much thanks alot it seems to works 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you have a test_date:

```
test_date = Date.new(2019,3,3)
```

and you calculate the expiry date adding 5 years (same day/month in 5 years):

```
expiry_date = test_date + 5.years
```

or adding exactly 1.825 days (5y * 365d):

```
expiry_date = test_date + (5*365).days
```

and now you want to know if that is expired:

```
today = Date.today
expired = today > expiry_date
```

or you want to know if it's in the rewrite period (after 3 years up to 5 years):

```
is_in_rewrite_period = today.between?(test_date + 3.years, expiry_date)
```

or

```
is_in_rewrite_period = today.between?(expiry_date - 2.years, expiry_date)
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Made use of the last option thanks alot <3

Comment: Be careful when doing date calculations: `test_date + 5.years` is not the same as `test_date + (5*365).days` (hint: leap years)

Comment: yes @Stefan, that's why I presented both, so OP chould choose according to requirements. I'll edit post to clarify it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ago`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-ago) and [`in`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-in) methods

```
test_date = Date.new(2019, 3, 3)

expiry_date = test_date.in(5.years).to_date

today = Date.today

today.in?(test_date.in(3.years).to_date..expiry_date)
today.in?(expiry_date.ago(2.years).to_date..expiry_date)
```